# Swiping through unlimited fragments - Confused over ViewPager process

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to create an app that pulls these Ron Swanson quotes from an api and displays them in a fragment. When the fragment is swiped, the app will go to another fragment and display a new quote. This process is supposed to repeat indefinitely.

Instead, the app loads to a blank screen. I have placed a button and TextView on the fragment, each with initial texts to determine if it has loads, but nothing ever appears.

P.S.: you may also notice some *comical* variable names and comments. I obviously didn't consider that I may need help when writing it (it's just a personal app for learning).

P.P.S.: I'm honestly not certain the site is even still up, but that shouldn't affect anything at this point.

Thanks to anyone who can help. Below is the 1) single java file of the app 2) activity_main.xml file.

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            //
            ViewPager pagingRon = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            PagerAdapter RonsPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            pagingRon.setAdapter(RonsPagerAdapter);
            pagingRon.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    // TOxDO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });

            //Initial AsyncTask for setting up first quote of the Great Swan
            RonSwanSetup ronSwansonOG = new RonSwanSetup();
            ronSwansonOG.execute();
        }

        private class RonSwanSetup extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... Socialism) {
                String Ronquoteson = ""; //Ron's wonderful first quote
                String Rondotcom = "http://ron-swanson-quotes.herokuapp.com/quotes"; //the website for fetching Ron's wonderful quotes
                String[] Ronsquotes = new String[1]; //Ron only speaks seldomly, which is the pinnacle of wisdom


                try {
                    URL Ronsurl = new URL(Rondotcom);
                    HttpURLConnection Ronsconnection = (HttpURLConnection) Ronsurl.openConnection();

                    BufferedReader thanksRon = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Ronsconnection.getInputStream()));
                    String current;

                    while((current = thanksRon.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Ronquoteson += current;
                    }

                    Ronsquotes[0] = Ronquoteson;

                } catch (Exception sorryRon) {
                    Ronsquotes[0] = "The app appears unable to do even the SIMPLEST THINGS CORRECTLY - Maybe try restarting it?";
                    sorryRon.printStackTrace();
                }

                publishProgress(Ronsquotes);

                return null;
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... Ronsquote) {
                TextView RonsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

                String RonQouteson = Ronsquote[0];
                RonsText.setText("Not Ron's Quote");//For testing

            }
        }

        public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            public CustomPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
                super(fm);
            }

            @Override
            // This method returns the fragment associated with
            // the specified position.
            // It is called when the Adapter needs a fragment
            // and it does not exist.
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {

                // Create fragment object
                RonFragSon fragment = new RonFragSon();

                // Attach some data to it that we'll
                // use to populate our fragment layouts
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putInt("page_position", position + 1);

                // Set the arguments on the fragment
                // that will be fetched
                fragment.setArguments(args);

                return fragment;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 3;
            }

        }

        public class RonFragSon extends Fragment {

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Inflate the layout resource that'll be returned
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swansons_fragment, container, false);

                // Get the arguments that was supplied when
                // the fragment was instantiated in the
                // CustomPagerAdapter
                Bundle args = getArguments();
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.text)).setText("Page");

                return rootView;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_Swangrid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40" 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!--   I don't think this is necessary, but don't want to get rid of it in case I'm wrong
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/Swanson_cant_container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/RonSwan1stQuote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/RonSwan2ndQuote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/RonSwan3rdQuote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    -->
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Cannot GET /quotes

Comment: Ya I'm more just trying to figure out how to get the fragments to actually display, even if the app can't be made completely.

Comment: check here https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html